# Horizontal slide menu calling Activity and caused NullPointerException after resume

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

My ActivityA has a horizontal slide menu that contains one button.
Here is the behaviour:

1) During onClick, it will call ActivityB via startActivityForResult() for users to select a category group.

2) Then, it will call another activity, ActivityC for users to select a sub-category.

3) After that, it will return back to the ActivityA. (Both ActivityB and ActivityC call finish(), after they are done.)

Right after resume to ActivityA, the app is crashed and here is what I saw in Logcat. None of them are pointing to my code. Any suggestion please?

** And, I just found out that the NullPointer happens in CustomHorizontalScrollView.onLayout()
Is that because the scroll menu losing focus after resume? Or, it's confused with which TargetFragment should it display?? I tried putting in try-catch for that NullPointer inside onLayout() so that my app doesn't FC. The scroll menu and the main layout are displayed just fine. But only the search result didn't get displayed.

Activity A: source code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    scrollView = (CustomHorizontalScrollView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_menu, null);
    setContentView(scrollView);

    menu = inflater.inflate(R.layout.horz_scroll_menu, null);
    app = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_list, null);

    btnSlide = (ImageView) app.findViewById(R.id.ib_slide_menu);
    btnSlide.setOnClickListener(new ClickListenerForScrolling(scrollView, menu));      

    fAdsSearch = (AdsSearchFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.f_search);
    fActionbar = (ActionBarFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.f_actionbar);
    fAdsSearch.setTargetFragment(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.f_main), 0);
scrollView.initViews(new View[] {menu, app}, 1, new SizeCallbackForMenu(btnSlide));
}
```

slide_menu.xml: source code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CustomHorizontalScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:background="#00ffffff" 
android:padding="0px"
android:layout_margin="0px" 
android:fadingEdge="none" 
android:fadingEdgeLength="0px"
android:scrollbars="none">
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/top" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:background="#ffffffff" 
    android:padding="0px" 
    android:layout_margin="0px">
</LinearLayout>
</CustomHorizontalScrollView>
```

horz_scroll_menu.xml: source code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/f_filter_menu"
    android:name="MenuFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</fragment>
</LinearLayout>
```

main_list.xml: source code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/f_actionbar"
    android:name="ActionBarFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/f_search"
    android:name="SearchFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/f_main"
    android:name="MainFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Logcat error:

```
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.widget.Spinner.makeAndAddView(Spinner.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.widget.Spinner.layout(Spinner.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.widget.Spinner.onLayout(Spinner.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.onLayout(HorizontalScrollView.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
02-08 15:57:12.959: E/AndroidRuntime(19322):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: print your Activity A code.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be that this NullPointerException has nothing to do with the slide menu. It's because I clean up the list data by setting adapter to null. Thanks for all your help.